# local Notification on click open an activity

Tags: android, notifications

I have a local notification which is set in one of my receivers. Onclick of notification I want to open a specific activity. Below is my code.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Its Your day!!")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(times, builder.build());
```

But this is not working. On Click of notification it just removes notification from status bar. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Did you tried after closing the app. SINGLE_TOP will pass the intent in `onNewIntent()` if MainActivity is alive .

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

instead of this :

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

use this codes before your notification builder code.

now this is the full version :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Its Your day!!")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(times, notificationBuilder.build());
```

try to use this. i hope you will get you desire answer.

**UPDATE**
here is the sample project : https://github.com/ImtiazDipto01/SimpleNotification

Comment: @madhuriHR  check the UPDATE section, i added a sample project. let me know if you get any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as `Flag` on your `Intent. Like -

`notificationIntent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

Also provide unique id for notification. like -

```
    int uniqueNotificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, uniqueNotificationId , notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also on -

```
manager.notify(uniqueNotificationId , builder.build());
```

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` only makes sense with the same `requestCode`. Unique ID for each `PendingIntent` creates a new `PendingIntent` each time.